# Aligning HTML columns in scrollable table

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have the following HTML, which contains a scrollable table.  Although I have specified column widths in every instance (except where colspan is greater than 1), I cannot get the data columns to align with the header, and I do not see why.

I suspect the issue is the result of not understanding how CSS styles inter-relate, but this is where I am.  I would love to find a good reference that could help me in that understanding.  Where you now see 'table.main.innerb.subt' I have tried a number of combinations, including simply '.subt' but the issue remains.

What is wrong with the code that prevents the table from aligning?  And where is a good "dummy's guide" type of reference that would help with the initial understanding hurdle?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 6 November 2007), see www.w3.org"
name="generator">
<meta content='text/html; charset=us-ascii' http-equiv=
'Content-Type'>
<title>10% Analysis Report for 11/18/2012</title>

<style type='text/css'>

caption.head {
  font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:18pt;
  color:#333333;
  border:0 solid white;
 }
table.main {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid gray;
  }
table.main th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #dedede;
  }
table.main th.empno {width:6em;}
table.main th.empname {width:30em;}
table.main th.date {width:8em;}
table.main th.amt {width:8em;}
table.main th.pct {width:5em;}
table.main th.dir {width:3em;}
table.main th.oicode {width:3em;}

table.main.innerb.subt th.empno {width:6em;}
table.main.innerb.subt th.empname {width:30em;}
table.main.innerb.subt th.date {width:8em;}
table.main.innerb.subt th.amt {width:8em;}
table.main.innerb.subt th.pct {width:5em;}
table.main.innerb.subt th.dir {width:3em;}
table.main.innerb.subt th.oicode {width:3em;}
table.main th.line2 {

  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #dedede;
  }
table.main tr.shade {
  background-color: NavajoWhite;
  }
table.main td {
  padding: 2px 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  }
table.main td.oicode {
  border:0 solid white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  width: 4em;
  }
table.main td.oicode2 {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  width: 4em;
  }
table.main td.oiamt {
  border:0 solid white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 4em;
  }
table.main td.oiamt2 {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 4em;
  }
table.main td.empno {width:6em;}
table.main td.empname {width:30em;}
table.main td.date {width:8em;}
table.main td.amt {width:8em;}
table.main td.pct {width:5em;}
table.main td.dir {width:3em;}
table.main td.oicode {width:3em;}

table.main.innerb.subt td.empno {width:6em;}
table.main.innerb.subt td.empname {width:30em;}
table.main.innerb.subt td.date {width:8em;}
table.main.innerb.subt td.amt {width:8em;}
table.main.innerb.subt td.pct {width:5em;}
table.main.innerb.subt td.dir {width:3em;}
table.main.innerb.subt td.oicode {width:3em;}

.empno {width:6em;}
.empname {width:30em;}
.date {width:8em;}
.amt {width:8em;}
.pct {width:5em;}
.dir {width:3em;}
.oicode {width:3em;}

.innerb {height:20em; overflow:auto;}

</style>

<style type="text/css">
 div.c1 {valign: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<div class='c1'></div>
<table align='center' class='main' summary='Script output'>
    <caption class='head'>
    10% Analysis Report for 11/18/2012
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='2' scope='col'>Employee</th>
            <th colspan='2' scope='col'>Period End</th>
            <th colspan='2' scope='col'>Gross Amount</th>
            <th class='pct' rowspan='2' scope='col'>Gross Chg&nbsp;%</th>
            <th class='amt' rowspan='2' scope='col'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Difference&nbsp;</th>
            <th class='dir' rowspan='2' scope='col'>Dir</th>
            <th colspan='2' scope='col'>Net Amount</th>
            <th class='amt' rowspan='2' scope='col'>Net Chg&nbsp;%</th>
            <th colspan='5' scope='col'>Current Period Amounts</th>
            <th colspan='3' scope='col'>Other Incomes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class='empno' scope='col'>xxxxxx</th>
            <th class='empname' scope='col'>Name</th>
            <th class='date' scope='col'>Latest</th>
            <th class='date' scope='col'>Previous</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Latest</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Previous</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Latest</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Previous</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Overtime</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>DCP</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>RRP</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>OOP</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Other</th>
            <th class='oicode' scope='col'>Code</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Curr</th>
            <th class='amt' scope='col'>Prev</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Footer</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='20'>
                <div class="innerb">
                    <table class='subt' summary='script output'>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='2'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='2'>Howya&nbsp;Doin</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>7,241.67</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>6,325.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>14.49</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>916.67</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>4,246.38</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>3,660.80</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>16.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>916.67</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>825.00</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;916.67&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;SH3&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;825.00&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;825.00&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='2'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='2'>Hoosier&nbsp;Friend</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>2,174.04</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,961.54</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>10.83</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>212.50</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,511.09</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,363.72</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>10.81</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>212.50</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;65.38&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT1&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;147.12&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='1'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='1'>Wanna B.&nbsp;Special</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,282.69</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>6,565.38</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>50.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,282.69</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='1'>Down</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>2,138.21</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,975.41</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>46.21</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,282.69</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;VAC&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;3,282.69&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='2'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='2'>Frisky&nbsp;Muffin</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>2,223.50</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>2,020.38</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>10.05</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>203.12</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,561.17</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,400.01</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>11.51</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>203.12</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;41.49&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT1&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;161.63&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='2'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='2'>Howya&nbsp;Holdenup</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='2'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>2,110.31</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,984.62</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>6.33</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>125.69</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,643.36</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>1,442.42</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='2'>13.93</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>125.69</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;66.15&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT1&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;59.54&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='1'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='1'>Failin&nbsp;Groovy</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>300.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>4,876.92</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>93.85</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>4,576.92</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='1'>Down</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>191.79</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,514.42</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>94.54</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>300.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;RR2&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;300.00&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='1'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='1'>Hoosier&nbsp;Cousin</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,076.92</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>2,461.54</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>25.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>615.38</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>2,032.98</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>1,670.48</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>21.70</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>615.38</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;OT1&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;615.38&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='1'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='1'>Sunny&nbsp;Skies</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>4,913.46</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>4,211.54</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>16.67</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>701.92</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,170.59</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>2,745.88</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>15.47</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>701.92</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;HOL&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;701.92&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='3'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='3'>Wanna B.&nbsp;Somebody</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='3'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='3'>10/21/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>11,788.46</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>35,365.38</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='3'>66.67</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>23,576.92</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='3'>Down</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>6,848.28</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>18,911.71</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='3'>63.79</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='3'>11,788.46</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;EX1&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;353.65&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;SEV&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;11,788.46&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;VAC&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;23,576.92&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='1'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='1'>Sporty&nbsp;Cabin</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>250.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,488.46</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>92.83</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,238.46</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='1'>Down</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>138.70</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>1,958.82</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>92.92</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>250.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;RR2&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;250.00&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='1'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='1'>Giant&nbsp;Cricket</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>288.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>720.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>60.00</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>432.00</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='1'>Down</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>265.81</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>622.38</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>57.29</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>288.00</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;PDW&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;288.00&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;720.00&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='SHADE'>
                            <td class='empno' rowspan='1'>xxxxxx</td>
                            <td class='empname' rowspan='1'>Blue&nbsp;Lagoon</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/18/2012</td>
                            <td class='date' rowspan='1'>11/04/2012</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>5,927.54</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,236.92</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>83.12</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>2,690.62</td>
                            <td class='dir' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>3,889.05</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>2,253.43</td>
                            <td align='right' class='pct' rowspan='1'>72.58</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align='right' class='amt' rowspan='1'>-34.00</td>
                            <td class="oicode">&nbsp;DBL&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;-34.00&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="oiamt">&nbsp;-2,724.62&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start with validating your markup with http://validator.w3.org and your CSS code with http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Your code contains a lot of mistakes, such as mixing `<div>`s in `<table>` and `width=4em`. I think you'd better first have your code cleaned up, because the behavior of this kind of code is not expectable.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela and rhgb - You were both correct (thanks for the links!).  Now the code is cleaned up - at least TIDY and the two sites Jukka mentioned have no objections.  Still, the alignment problem persists.  What can I do/read next to resolve?  Thanks again.

Comment: @rhgb The code is valid! Please see. :)

Comment: @Dennis Your code is valid. Only thing is it is clumsy. You need to clean it up.

Comment: I counted 20 columns within your first set of th declarations but on 16 the the second set of table headers

Comment: @rebootreuserecycle.com - Thanks, but (I could be wrong) I don't think you accounted for rowspan.  The way I count it, the columns should align.  The number of columns expected in the second row is 16 when you factor out the four rowspan=2 columns, right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Thanks for your advice.  Care to elaborate a little?  (I would have said, "Only thing is it doesn't work.  At least not with Firefox and IE.") What does "Clean it up" mean?

Comment: Use something like freeformatter.com or similar sites to format your code. Also, avoid those classes generated by MS Office or software of that sort...

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Thanks, but formatting will not help this issue. Also, please indicate where you see MS Office tags.  This is all hand-rolled.

Comment: Err... Sorry, the `oiamt` looked like that. Stupid eyes of mine! :P

Answer (score 0):

When you use nested tables so that the data rows are in an inner table, it becomes very difficult to make the columns aligned. The reason is that the columns of the inner table are not connected with the columns of the outer table in any way.

In this case, it seems that part of the differences is caused by different horizontal paddings in the header cells vs. the data cells. So check the padding settings (it’s probably best to reduce the paddings in this process, since the table is very wide and large padding makes the situation worse).

Comment: thanks again.  Every td and th style now has "border-width: 1px; padding: 2px 0px;" (Should I edit my question with that code?  I think it would be confusing to post as a new answer when I know it's not an answer at all!  Please advise.)  While it did make a difference, it was not the one I expected.  It looks to me like none of my WIDTH:xEM are being honored now at all.  I can make them 80em, for example, and they might shift a little; or might not.  In general, everything is collapsed horizontally.

Comment: @Dennis, it might be best to post a jsfiddle demonstrating the current version. Regarding widths, they are not necessarily implemented exactly (though setting `table { table-layout: fixed }` might help, but it could also cause serious trouble if the content does not fit).

Comment: Thank you, Sir.  Didn't know about jsfiddle either.  Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/2EzK2/   Setting table {table-layout: fixed;} and the same for table.main seems to have no effect.  Hmmm...